# App with nested UINavigationController crashes in iOS SDK 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm in the process of migrating an App to the current iOS SDK. Its root controller is `UINavigationController` with another `UINavigationController` as first view controller.

The application now crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` caused by some kind of infinite recursion, but I can't make sense of the strack trace. As far as I can tell, nothing has changed expect some project settings to make it compile on the current SDK.

I created a new Navigation-based Application and added a nested `UINavigationController`, which also crashed the application. Is nesting `UINavigationController`s generally a bad idea?

Any hints what might be causing this or how to interpret the stack trace and debug the problem are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, nesting navigation controllers is a bad idea. `pushViewController:animated:` will even throw an exception if you pass it a navigation controller. Perhaps you should open a separate question about how better to structure your view controllers and UI flow.

Comment: Weird, IB lets you add a NIB with a nested `UINavigationController`. I'll see if I can restructure my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work when you set the navigationbar of the parent navigation controller to hidden (in interface builder or in code) before loading the view:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it does seem odd to have a nested UINavigationController, but heck what do I know. What is the root view controller of the nested nav controller? Hopefully not the top nav controller.

Comment: They are nested because I needed to have two separate view stacks. That might be odd, no doubt, but it used to work and stopped after upgrading the SDK. And no, there is no circular reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

1. Create a new UINavigationController
2. In `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillLoad`alloc and init the controller to whichever root you want
3. Resize the NavigationController's view and add it as subview to the parent viewCOntroller's view (I have self.contentView)

BOOM!!

here is the code..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.contentView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.bounds.size.width, self.contentView.bounds.size.height)];

mNavController =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:myNestedRootController]; /
[self.mNavController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.bounds.size.width, self.contentView.bounds.size.height)];
[self.mNavController setNavigationBarHidden:YES]; //optional
[self.contentView addSubview:self.mNavController.view];
}
```

Actually you can skip the contentView and have the `mNavController's` view directly on `viewcontroller's view` (my bad)

I have a method to push (only push) a new VC

```
-(void)moveToContentViewController:(PM_BaseContentVC *)contentvc animated:(BOOL)animated{
[self.mNavController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]; //silently pop the previous viewcontroller
[self.mNavController pushViewController:contentvc animated:YES]; //push new viewcontrolelr
[self.contentView addSubview:self.mNavController.view]; //add the view
}
```

sugestions and optimizations are welcome :)